# Disable Function in IE7 - Best Practice

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, optimization

I would like to disable a JQuery function ONLY in IE7.

What would be the best way of doing it?.

```
select_menu: function() {
            $('select').selectmenu({
                style: 'dropdown',
                appendTo: 'footer#footer form span'
            });

            $('form.filters * select').each(function() {
                $(this).selectmenu({
                    style: 'dropdown',
                    appendTo: $(this).closest('span'),
                    "open": function(){
                        var menu = jQuery('ul#'+$(this).attr('id')+'-menu');
                        menu.hide().slideDown('slow');
                    },
                    "close": function(){
                        var menu = jQuery('ul#'+$(this).attr('id')+'-menu');
                        menu.slideUp('slow');
                    }
                });
            });
        },
```

Comment: `footer#footer` is overkill, all you need is `#footer`, you're being too specific. ID's must be unique, so specifying that an element with `x` id is a `footer` element is not needed. The same goes for `ul#id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this directly after the plugin's script to disable the plugin in IE7

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script>
$.fn.selectmenu = function() { return this };
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Though you could probably instead fix the plugin to work in IE7, that would be the best way to fix the problem.

Comment: That means jQuery isn't included... or you are using $.noConflict?

Comment: You did put this code in your HTML right? not in script tags?

Comment: the code i posted should not throw a $ is undefined if you placed it after the selectmenu.js